# Get Selected row item from gridview2

Tags: vb.net, winforms, devexpress

I have a one gridcontrol (GridControl1)
Inside thid gridcontrol, there is two Grid Views (GridView1 & GridView2)
I want to get value of Selected row item in GridView2 and put it in a textbox.
on GridView1 I Can Get That using This Code:

```
txtEmpId.Text = GridView1.GetFocusedRowCellDisplayText(colEmp_Id)
```

But if I Select any Row on GridView2, nothing I will get.

Is there any method to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have using the master-detail please  review the [help article describing in detail](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument783)

In you GridControl you must handle the `Grid_MasterRowExpanded` and then add programmaticuly a handle to `gridView.SelectionChanged` ,this code will help you

```
 Private Sub Grid_MasterRowExpanded(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.CustomMasterRowEventArgs) Handles Grid.MasterRowExpanded
        Dim view As GridView = sender
        Dim detail As GridView = view.GetDetailView(e.RowHandle, e.RelationIndex)
        detail.OptionsSelection.MultiSelect = True

        If e.RowHandle = 0 Or e.RowHandle = 1 Then
            AddHandler detail.SelectionChanged, AddressOf detail_SelectionChanged
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub detail_SelectionChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As DevExpress.Data.SelectionChangedEventArgs)

        viewSelected = sender

        Dim ro As DataRowView = viewSelected.GetFocusedRow
       txtEmpId.Text = ro.Item("colEmp_Id") 

    End Sub
```

Comment: same issue, textbox still empty. I'm using master-details.

Comment: ok use   Dim ro As DataRowView = viewSelected.GetFocusedRow;   txtEmpId.Text = ro.Item("colEmp_Id")

Comment: Private Sub GridView2_FocusedRowChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles GridView2.FocusedRowChanged
        If GridView2.SelectedRowsCount = 1 Then
            Dim ro As DataRowView = CType(GridView2.GetFocusedRow, DataRowView)
            txtEmpId.Text = CType(ro.Item("colEmp_Id"), String)
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: ok i have edit the answer, you must handle the gridView.SelectionChanged  event ,try and let me know